# While loop not working properly with Python

Tags: python, while-loop

So I am a noob in Python & I m making an project for my school so I am having an issue with While loops, the voice API (espeak) is again & again repeating with the 12th option, which It is repeating it continuosly until I forced quit it. So this is the section where I added espeak

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr

engine = pyttsx3.init('espeak')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[2].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

& this is the while loop part

```
while choice != 17:
    if choice == 1:
        print("""
        If you want to make a website, you can see this site
        https://websitesetup.org/
        If you want to make a website you might learn HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language). It is the core of the website. You also need to learn CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) for making website responsive & beautiful & JS (JavaScript) to make website functional properly. CSS & JS are not required but recommended.
        """)
        speak("""
        If you want to make a website, you can see this site
        https://websitesetup.org/
        If you want to make awhile website you might learn HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language). It is the core of the website. You also need to learn CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) for making website responsive & beautiful & JS (JavaScript) to make website functional properly. CSS & JS are not required but recommended.
        """)

    if choice == 2:
        print("""
        If you want to make an application, you need to know that we can make application either for Android or iOS. For Android apps there are many platforms like Plezmo, MIT App Inventor, MIT Scratch etc. They use the block coding... If you want to make text coding then you can use Java. If you want to make iOS apps then you need to have a mac device & you can program in Swift language.
        You can also see: https://www.biznessapps.com/blog/how-to-build-a-mobile-app-in-12-easy-steps/
        """)
        speak("""
        If you want to make an application, you need to know that we can make application either for Android or iOS. For Android apps there are many platforms like Plezmo, MIT App Inventor, MIT Scratch etc. They use the block coding... If you want to make text coding then you can use Java. If you want to make iOS apps then you need to have a mac device & you can program in Swift language.
        You can also see: https://www.biznessapps.com/blog/how-to-build-a-mobile-app-in-12-easy-steps/
        """)
        
    if choice == 3:
        print("""
        If you want to learn Machine Learning, then you can learn Python. There are many concepts of Machine Learning, & the learning curve is very huge so it is not very possible to learn all the concepts of Machine Learning. There are many modules to learn for Machine Learning like Scikit-learn, Theano, Tensorflow etc. They all have different jobs. If you want to have a simple idea of Machine Learning then you can try out Teachable Machine (https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) for having a simple idea of Machine Learning. 
        You can also see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-start-learning-machine-learning/
        """)
        speak("""
        If you want to learn Machine Learning, then you can learn Python. There are many concepts of Machine Learning, & the learning curve is very huge so it is not very possible to learn all the concepts of Machine Learning. There are many modules to learn for Machine Learning like Scikit-learn, Theano, Tensorflow etc. They all have different jobs. If you want to have a simple idea of Machine Learning then you can try out Teachable Machine (https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) for having a simple idea of Machine Learning. 
        You can also see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-start-learning-machine-learning/
        """)
    if choice == 4:
        print("""
        If you want to learn Hacking, you need to learn about Linux (Command Line), Networking, Python, some modules of Python like Scapy, Requests, Cryptography etc. Also you have three types of Hackers available.
        1. Black Hat Hackers, those who do hacking for malicious intenet & have a intent to harm the computer. They do things for illegal things.
        2. White Hat Hackers, also known as Ethical Hackers are those who use the same technology as Black Hat Hackers, but for a good intent, for the security of a Computer, & to get track of Black Hat Hacker
        3. Grey Hat Hackers, are a mix of both, they do things to check the security of the system but without the user awareness, but do not have an intent to harm the computer. 
        """)
        speak("""
        If you want to learn Hacking, you need to learn about Linux (Command Line), Networking, Python, some modules of Python like Scapy, Requests, Cryptography etc. Also you have three types of Hackers available.
        1. Black Hat Hackers, those who do hacking for malicious intenet & have a intent to harm the computer. They do things for illegal things.
        2. White Hat Hackers, also known as Ethical Hackers are those who use the same technology as Black Hat Hackers, but for a good intent, for the security of a Computer, & to get track of Black Hat Hacker
        3. Grey Hat Hackers, are a mix of both, they do things to check the security of the system but without the user awareness, but do not have an intent to harm the computer.
        See this site for more info: https://www.wikihow.com/Start-Learning-to-Hack
        """)
    if choice == 5:
        print("""
        If you want to learn Python, then you can refer to some tutorials which are made for Python. Python is a programming language which has an easy to understand syntax & can be used in many fields like Machine Learning, Game Development, GUI Development, Website Development, etc. It is one of the most wanted languages in demand (According to Stack Overflow). Many companies use this language like Netflix, Google, Instagram etc,
        Refer to this site for learning Python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/
        """)
        speak("""
        If you want to learn Python, then you can refer to some tutorials which are made for Python. Python is a programming language which has an easy to understand syntax & can be used in many fields like Machine Learning, Game Development, GUI Development, Website Development, etc. It is one of the most wanted languages in demand (According to Stack Overflow). Many companies use this language like Netflix, Google, Instagram etc,
        Refer to this site for learning Python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/
        """)
    if choice == 6:
        print("This is the site for ATL Innovation Mission: https://aim.gov.in/")
        speak("This is the site for ATL Innovation Mission: https://aim.gov.in/")
    if choice == 7:
        print("Website is slow due to a technical issue at their site only, so kindly have patience & it will load soon!")
        speak("Website is slow due to a technical issue at their site only, so kindly have patience & it will load soon!")
    if choice == 8:
        print("This is a technical issue from their site itself. Due to a lot of traffic sometimes the site doesn't open. So you can wait for sometimes or try at one of the times like early morning or late night, so there might be less chances for having the site unusable. Sometimes the site is made for some browser online like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, so if it doesn't open try from any other browser.")
        speak("This is a technical issue from their site itself. Due to a lot of traffic sometimes the site doesn't open. So you can wait for sometimes or try at one of the times like early morning or late night, so there might be less chances for having the site unusable. Sometimes the site is made for some browser online like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, so if it doesn't open try from any other browser.")
    if choice == 9:
        print("The website has issues with the login also. It also turns short password into long due to security issues. Login issues are sometimes because of the browser. For example, Brave browser is not compatible & it will show invalid password even though it is correct. 2 browsers working are Google Chrome & Mozilla Firefox")
        speak("The website has issues with the login also. It also turns short password into long due to security issues. Login issues are sometimes because of the browser. For example, Brave browser is not compatible & it will show invalid password even though it is correct. 2 browsers working are Google Chrome & Mozilla Firefox")
    if choice == 10:
        print("To try to repair or improve something without having the proper skill or knowledge")
        speak("To try to repair or improve something without having the proper skill or knowledge")
        if choice == 11:
            print("""
Corruption
Illiteracy
Education System
Basic Sanitation
Healthcare System
Poverty
Pollution
Women’s Safety
Infrastructure
Unemployment
Agricultural Distress
The rise in Global Protectionism
            """)
        speak("""
Corruption
Illiteracy
Education System
Basic Sanitation
Healthcare System
Poverty
Pollution
Women’s Safety
Infrastructure
Unemployment
Agricultural Distress
The rise in Global Protectionism
        """)

    if choice == 12:
        print("""
Step 1: Identify & Meet with Stakeholders. A stakeholder is anyone who is affected by the results of your project plan. ...
Step 2: Set & Prioritize Goals. ...
Step 3: Define Deliverables. ...
Step 4: Create the Project Schedule. ...
Step 5: Identify Issues and Complete a Risk Assessment. ...
Step 6: Present the Project Plan to Stakeholders.
        """)
    speak("""
Step 1: Identify & Meet with Stakeholders. A stakeholder is anyone who is affected by the results of your project plan. ...
Step 2: Set & Prioritize Goals. ...
Step 3: Define Deliverables. ...
Step 4: Create the Project Schedule. ...
Step 5: Identify Issues and Complete a Risk Assessment. ...
Step 6: Present the Project Plan to Stakeholders.
    """)

    if choice == 13:
        print("""
Come up with a simple project.
Get the software you'll need.
Join communities about how to start coding.
Read a few books.
How to start coding with YouTube.
Listen to a podcast.
Run through a tutorial.
Try some games on how to start coding.
Take a Coding Bootcamp
You can also learn coding from these Coding Classes and Programs
Codecademy. ...
Udemy. ...
Skillcrush's FREE Coding Camp. ...
freeCodeCamp. ...
Khan Academy. ...
Web Fundamentals. ...
w3schools. ...
Code.org.etc
        """)
        speak("""
Come up with a simple project.
Get the software you'll need.
Join communities about how to start coding.
Read a few books.
How to start coding with YouTube.
Listen to a podcast.
Run through a tutorial.
Try some games on how to start coding.
Take a Coding Bootcamp
You can also learn coding from these Coding Classes and Programs
Codecademy. ...
Udemy. ...
Skillcrush's FREE Coding Camp. ...
freeCodeCamp. ...
Khan Academy. ...
Web Fundamentals. ...
w3schools. ...
Code.org.etc
        """)

    if choice == 14:
        print("""
    No, coding is not hard to learn. However, like anything new, it's not easy to start, and how difficult a time one has with learning to code will vary across a number of factors. The point is, learning to code isn't impossible; or, it's not as impossible as it might seem when it comes to getting your kids involved.
        """)
        speak("""
    No, coding is not hard to learn. However, like anything new, it's not easy to start, and how difficult a time one has with learning to code will vary across a number of factors. The point is, learning to code isn't impossible; or, it's not as impossible as it might seem when it comes to getting your kids involved.
        """)
    
    if choice == 15:
        print("""
    The job can be stressful at times, but computer programmers are compensated well for any anxiety they might experience. Many jobs in this profession are being outsourced to other countries where pay is lower, saving companies money.
        """)
        speak("""
    The job can be stressful at times, but computer programmers are compensated well for any anxiety they might experience. Many jobs in this profession are being outsourced to other countries where pay is lower, saving companies money.
        """)

    if choice == 16:
        print("""
    Computer programmers get paid well, with an average salary of $63,903 per year in 2020. Beginner programmers earn about $50k and experienced coders earn around $85k.
        """)
        speak("""
    Computer programmers get paid well, with an average salary of $63,903 per year in 2020. Beginner programmers earn about $50k and experienced coders earn around $85k.
        """)

if choice == 17:
    print("Ok Exiting...")
    speak("Ok exiting...")
```

& this is the 12th option

```
    if choice == 12:
        print("""
        Step 1: Identify & Meet with Stakeholders. A stakeholder is anyone who is affected by the results of your project plan. ...
        Step 2: Set & Prioritize Goals. ...
        Step 3: Define Deliverables. ...
        Step 4: Create the Project Schedule. ...
        Step 5: Identify Issues and Complete a Risk Assessment. ...
        Step 6: Present the Project Plan to Stakeholders.
        """)
        
    speak("""
        Step 1: Identify & Meet with Stakeholders. A stakeholder is anyone who is affected by the results of your project plan. ...
        Step 2: Set & Prioritize Goals. ...
        Step 3: Define Deliverables. ...
        Step 4: Create the Project Schedule. ...
        Step 5: Identify Issues and Complete a Risk Assessment. ...
        Step 6: Present the Project Plan to Stakeholders.
        """)
```

Comment: your indentation is off. also what is `choice` and how you get its value. Post [mre]. There is no need to show all 17 virtually the same choices. Of course all this repetitive code can be simplified.

Comment: You never update `choice` within the loop

Comment: I think if u  add `break` after if statement,then it might work

Answer (score 0):

You should update `choice` in the loop somewhere. The while condition in the cases where `choice` is not equal to `17` will repeat infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend inserting your `guess` variable at the beginning inside the while loop that way after any input that isn't `17`, it will loop back to the beginning of the while loop, which will give you another opportunity to select another option.

```
while True:
  guess = int(input('input message'))
  if guess == 1:
    # Do something...
  elif guess == 2:
    # Do something else...
  elif guess == 3:
    # Do something else again...
  elif guess == 4:
    # Quit the program for example...
```

Another way is to `break` out of the loop as Code2D suggested, but that's only if you want to end the loop after only choosing 1 option.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you need to update the `choice` variable from inside the loop. Once the loop starts, only what is inside it will be executed, in your case, `choice` was given a value before the loop, so it keeps the same value (which is never 17) and repeats.

What you should do is add a way to update choice inside the loop:

```py
...
while choice != 17:
    choice = int(input("What is your choice? "))
    ...
...
```

You didn't post your entire script, so I'm assuming you are giving `choice` a value before the loop. Move that assignment to the beginning of the loop; if for some reason you need it before the loop, you can place the assignment at the end of the loop, so when it first runs, it doesn't directly ask you to make a choice, only after it completed.